# Remove part of the Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request.form

In a C# MVC3 solution I'm passing the request.form as a string to a webservice (I understand it would be much better to break it down and populate a model but it's compromised with old code and mainly with time) and at a step the string is huge due to many options and failed in the service.

Actually I won't need all of this options, which are basically several dropdownlists from which I just need one of them, so I'm trying to figure out how to change the request.form in order to remove the redundant ones and just keep the one selected.

To put this into context, this should be part of the string (just a middle chunk of it)

```
NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_SHR*16344*MAT*1*2500*1600=0&NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_SHR*16344*MAT*2*5500*6200=0&NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_39S*16344*EVE*1*1500*0=2
```

And I would like to remove all of the options appart from (in this portion) the last one wich =2. This 0's and the 2 come from a dropdown list which name is all the rest of the parameter (ie NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_39S*16344*EVE*1*1500*0) although it may be completely different, not always follow this pattern.

Is there any way I can get rid of the dropdown lists I leave to 0 in the request.form before submitting (or even in the controller would be acceptable)?

Comment: do you know the names of the other elements in the collection? So the only one that's dynamic is the one you need?

Comment: Although are quite a few the rest are known names

Comment: I'm trying with this script                $("select").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 0)
            $(this).remove();
    });                                                                 But not luck yet

Comment: Ok, the previous code works, although I was looking for the incorrect id of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out values that you don't want to keep:

```
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_SHR*16344*MAT*1*2500*1600=0&NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_SHR*16344*MAT*2*5500*6200=0&NG2BEF01-16344-181-E-16344-0-SHW_39S*16344*EVE*1*1500*0=2");
string result = string.Join("&", values.Cast<string>().Where(key => values[key] == "2").Select(key => string.Format("{0}={1}", key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[key]))));
// The result variable will contain only kvps where the value equals 2
```